# Duda isset condicionales PHP

Tags: php

Me encontraba escribiendo código en localhost y me saltó un error que no me da en mi servidor por ende tengo una duda básica talvez..

Esto es lo mismo

```
if(isset($VariablePrueba) && $VariablePrueba == 1) {
    # Código
}
```

que esto

```
if(isset($VariablePrueba) == 1) {
    # Código
}
```

Siempre lo utilicé de la segunda manera y nunca tuve problemas, pero ahora en localhost veo que no se cumple lo de adentro (es un echo lo de adentro)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: En realidad no da error pero no se ejecuta el código que hay dentro (es un echo)

Comment: Es lo mismo `if(true && $variable == 1)` que `if(true == 1)` ? Nop, en la primera compruebas que exista variable prueba **Y** que su valor sea uno, en la segunda intentas comparar TRUE (boolean) y 1 (integer)

Answer (score 2):

**¿Qué hace la función isset?**

`isset()` determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL, retornará un `boolean`.

Analicemos tus condiciones.

**Primera condición**

```
if(isset($VariablePrueba) && $VariablePrueba == 1)
```

Acá en realidad hay dos condiciones, la primera validará que la variable `$VariablePrueba` exista dentro de tu código y no tenga un valor `null`, mientras que la segunda condición `$VariablePrueba == 1` validará que el contenido de la variable sea `1` o en su defecto `true`.

Lo ultimo pasa porque los booleanos en php se pueden utilizar como 0-1 o true-false, debido a que no es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado (Exceptuando las ultimas versiones de php que traen nuevas características, pero eso es otra cosa).
Para validar el tipo de dato y el valor debes usar `===`.

Entonces, ingresará al `if` solo cuando la variable exista y su valor sea 1 o true.

**Segunda condición**

```
isset($VariablePrueba) == 1
```

Esta condición es redundante, lo que hace es preguntar si la variable `$VariablePrueba` existe en tu código, posterior a eso reemplaza `isset()` por el valor de retorno de dicha función y ejecutará la condición.
Si la variable está definida y no es null, isset retornará un true, lo que luego se vuelve a comparar con el `==1` para afirmar que el resultado sea verdadero, pero esa resolución ya la hace el if por defecto, por eso es redundante. (recordar que el 1 en esta situación se está validando como un true y no como un numero, si agregas otro `=` a esa condición validará explícitamente por el 1, pero esta condición daria siempre false ya que isset retorna un boolean y nunca será igual a 1, por lo cual usar `===` acá no tiene sentido alguno.)

En este caso ingresará al if cuando la variable esté definida y no sea nulo, sin importar su contenido.

Esta condición debiera ser así `if(isset($VariablePrueba))`

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a lo que preguntas, no es lo mismo, son 2 condiciones en 1, aunque 1 no tendría razón de ser si la segunda se cumple, yo te recomendaría hacer primero la condición isset (comprueba si la variable trae un valor) y dentro de ese if el otro de if($VariablePrueba == 1) para comprobar si el valor que trae esa variable es 1

por ejempplo:

```
if(isset($VariablePrueba)) { // esta comprueba que la variable traiga un valor
   if($VariablePrueba == 1) // esta comprueba que el valor que trae es 1
   {
      // tu codigo aqui
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas en la documentación [de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) encontrarás que dicha función `isset()`:

- Comprueba si una variable esta definida

y

- Que dicha variable **NO** sea `NULL`

**Ejemplo 1**

```
$VariablePrueba = NULL;

if(isset($VariablePrueba) == 2) {
    echo 'yo';
}
```

La salida es? ..... nada pero ¿por qué?

Bueno por que si revisas las 2 condiciones que listé al inicio solo una de ellas se sumple, por que la variable si esta definida, pero la segunda que pide no sea nula no se cumple; lo cual quiere decir que la igualación que buscas en la otra comparación ni siquiera se lleva a cabo.

**Ejemplo 2**

```
$VariablePrueba = 3;

if(isset($VariablePrueba) == 2) {
    echo 'yo';
}
```

La salida es: **yo** pues de nuevo la función `isset` lo único que comprueba es que la variable esté definida y no sea nula.

Lo correcto entonces es evaluar 2 condiciones por separado, una para determinar lo que ya menciono al incio de esta respuesta y otra para evaluar si el valor de la variable coincide con uno en específico.

```
$VariablePrueba = 3;

if(isset($VariablePrueba) && $VariablePrueba === 2) {
    echo 'yo';
} else {
    echo 'el valor no coincide';
}
```

La salida es:

> el valor no coincide